# Wordpress template_redirect redirected too many times

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a hook that will check for parameters in URL and make redirection.

The script redirects fine regarding the url, but the error appears in the browser.

**www.sitename.sr redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'change_explore_url_for_cars');

function change_explore_url_for_cars(){

$type=$_GET['type'];

if($type == 'old_cars'){

    if(is_page('cars')&& isset($_GET['type']) && isset($_GET['sort']) ){ 
            wp_redirect(home_url('/cars/')."?type=old_cars&date_to=".date("Y-m-d")."&sort=newest");
            exit;
        }
    }

}
```

I dont know why is redirecting to manny times.

**UPDATE TO QUESTION, AND IT SOLVES THE PROBLEM OF REDIRECTION.

```
if($type == 'old_cars'){

    if(is_page('cars')&& isset($_GET['type']) && isset($_GET['sort']) && !isset($_GET['date_to'])){ 
            wp_redirect(home_url('/cars/')."?type=old_cars&date_to=".date("Y-m-d")."&sort=newest");
            exit;
        }
    }

}
```

After adding !isset($_GET['date_to'])) it solves the problem of redirection, as the statement if(is_page('cars')&& isset($_GET['type']) && isset($_GET['sort'])) is always true.

Comment: I see a neverending loop there. Assuming you redirect to the same page where the redirect conditions are being checked, the  `if($type == 'old_cars')` and `if(is_page('cars')&& isset($_GET['type']) && isset($_GET['sort']) )` will always be true and the redirect will always happen, creating a neverending loop. Still figuring out the easiest way to fix it.

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin adding && !isset($_GET['date_to']) solves the problem. if(is_page('cars')&& isset($_GET['type']) && isset($_GET['sort'])&& !isset($_GET['date_to']) )

Comment: That redirect looks very dodgy even after the fix. I am not quite sure what `$type == 'old_cars'` did to deserve a redirect dedicated explicitly to them. Besides you can still get `Undefined index` there. For example what if `isset($_GET['type'])` yealds false? But you happily do `$type=$_GET['type'];` without any checks. I suggest you review your code a little more, that redirect is still faulty and likely unnecessary at all as it doesn't really do anything, besides redirecting to the same page judging by OP.